# How many views can create in Oracle Database?

Tags: plsql, view, oracle11g, reporting

In hypothetical reporting department needs thousands of report everyday. Is this correct approach creating one report per view in Oracle 11g database? Does Oracle 11g have any limitations about creating views in database?

Sample of view code is as per below.

```
    CREATE VIEW Report1DXC AS
select Phonenumber,DECODE(package, 'Package1', 'Package Normal',
                    'Package2', 'Package Normal',
                    'Package3', 'Package Premium',
                    'Package4', 'Package Premium',
                    'Package5', 'Package Normal',
                    'Package6', 'Package Normal',
                    'Package7', 'Package Premium',
                    'Package8', 'Package Premium',
                    'Package9', 'Package Normal',
                    'Package10', 'Package Premium',
                    'Package11', 'Package Premium',
                    'Package12', 'Package Premium') package,renewid,Sub_End_date from (
SELECT DISTINCT subs_id, ContractNo, phonenumber as Phonenumber,
Package, renewid, Sub_End_date,function_mobnum_format(phonenumber) ph_correct
FROM 
subscription_history rh
INNER JOIN sub_equipment se ON rh.subs_id = se.subs_id AND rh.contractno = se.contractno
INNER JOIN packages pk ON rh.pkid = pk.pkid
INNER JOIN sub_phones ph ON rh.subs_id = ph.subs_id and rh.contractno=ph.contractno
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT subs_id, contractno, MAX(sub_end_date) AS sub_end_date FROM subscription_history where currentid=sequenceid GROUP BY subs_id, contractno) lr
ON rh.subs_id = lr.subs_id AND rh.contractno = lr.contractno
WHERE rh.currentid=rh.sequenceid
and emodel LIKE 'DXN%'
and rh.origin='R'
and rh.pcode=09
and rh.cancellation is null
AND TRUNC(lr.sub_end_date) > '29-JAN-18'
AND TRUNC(lr.sub_end_date-5) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
AND rh.subs_id not in (select subs_id from subscription_history where  TRUNC(sub_end_date-5) > TRUNC(SYSDATE))
and rh.subs_id not in (select subs_id from subscription_history where pkid IN ('PKID10','PKID11'))
ORDER BY rh.subs_id
)where ph_correct='OK';
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO there is not. Practically for cases where are too many view which depend on each other there is undocumented parameter _complex_view_merging. When you overuse this pattern the Oracle optimizer will simply give up and performance will be gone. This parameter somehow driver its behavior.

But it is still a better way, than wrapping SQL into PL/SQL functions and then using them in another SQLs.

If you do not create super complex dependencies between views it will be OK. You can even restrict access to underlying tables, and let users see, what they need to see.

PS: you should not use "order by" in views, if you want to use them in another view.

Comment: thanks for your tip about pointing unnecessary order by clause.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that [Logical database limits](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/limits003.htm#i288032) apply here. "Views" aren't specified directly, but "Tables" is what counts, and number of tables per database is **unlimited**.

Though, as [Ask Tom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=maximum-number-of-tables) says:

> ... a schema design that has 100,000 tables would be something I would seriously question. I'm not aware of any team of humans that could possibly design, implement, or maintain such a thing personally

So - create as many views as you want, you won't reach the limits.